# Detox _ Failed to type string because keyboard was not shown on screen

Tags: javascript, ios, testing, react-native, detox

I'm trying to test my react-native app using detox, waiting for a text input to be visible and typing text in it. My **spec JS file** looks like this:

```
describe('FiestTest', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative()
  })

  it('Login to a test account', async () => {
    // LoginPage: entering phone number moving to next page
    await expect(element(by.id('LoginPage-phoneInput'))).toBeVisible()
    await element(by.id('LoginPage-phoneInput')).typeText('<someNumber>')
  })
})
```

**And the error I get is:**

```
FiestTest
    1) Enter phone number and tap on button


  0 passing (15s)
  1 failing

  1) FiestTest Enter phone number and tap on button:
     Error: An action failed. Please refer to the error trace below.
Exception with Action: {
  "Action Name" : "Type '6219'",
  "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('ValidatePage-txtField')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('ValidatePage-txtField')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))"
}

Error Trace: [
  {
    "Description" : "Failed to type string '6219', because keyboard was not shown on screen.",
    "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code" : "2",
    "File Name" : "GREYKeyboard.m",
    "Function Name" : "+[GREYKeyboard typeString:inFirstResponder:error:]",
    "Line" : "168"
  }
]
```

**I'm using the following tools:**

```
$ npm outdate
Package                                  Current          Wanted         Latest  Location
apollo-client                              1.4.0           1.9.0          1.9.0  <appName>
babel-jest                                19.0.0          19.0.0         20.0.3  <appName>
babel-plugin-module-resolver               2.7.0           2.7.1          2.7.1  <appName>
eslint                                    3.19.0          3.19.0          4.4.1  <appName>
eslint-plugin-import                       2.2.0           2.7.0          2.7.0  <appName>
eslint-plugin-node                         4.2.2           4.2.3          5.1.1  <appName>
eslint-plugin-react                       6.10.3          6.10.3          7.1.0  <appName>
eslint-plugin-react-native                 2.3.2           2.3.2          3.0.1  <appName>
graphql-tag                                2.2.1           2.4.2          2.4.2  <appName>
jest                                      19.0.2          19.0.2         20.0.4  <appName>
moment-jalaali                             0.6.1           0.6.1          0.7.0  <appName>
native-base                                2.1.4           2.3.1          2.3.1  <appName>
react                             16.0.0-alpha.6  16.0.0-alpha.6         15.6.1  <appName>
react-apollo                               1.4.2          1.4.11         1.4.11  <appName>
react-native                              0.44.0          0.44.0         0.47.1  <appName>
react-native-adjust                       4.11.3          4.11.4         4.11.4  <appName>
react-native-fcm                           6.2.3           6.2.3          8.0.0  <appName>
react-native-popup-menu                    0.7.3           0.7.5          0.8.0  <appName>
react-native-router-flux                  3.39.1          3.41.0  4.0.0-beta.16  <appName>
react-native-sentry                       0.12.9         0.12.12         0.15.1  <appName>
react-native-smart-splash-screen           2.3.3           2.3.4          2.3.4  <appName>
react-test-renderer                       15.4.2          15.4.2         15.6.1  <appName>
redux                                      3.6.0           3.7.2          3.7.2  <appName>
redux-persist                              4.6.0           4.8.3          4.8.3  <appName>
```

**And this is my podfile:**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '<appName>' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for <appName>

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  #target '<appName>-tvOSTests' do
  #  inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  #end

  #target '<appName>Tests' do
  #  inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  #end

end

#target '<appName>-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for <appName>-tvOS

#  target '<appName>-tvOSTests' do
#    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
#  end

#end
```

**For now I'm just using a sleep command like bellow in order to give me time to manually insert the string. However, this should not be a permanent solution...**

```
function sleep (ms) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

await sleep(milliseconds)
// what needs to happen after I manually enter the code
```

I've also commented in a Detox issue on GitHub, but was wondering if anyone has had the same experience and has found a solution here.

*Thanks for your assistance in advance!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run

```
await element(by.id('LoginPage-phoneInput')).tap();
```

before

```
await element(by.id('LoginPage-phoneInput')).typeText('<someNumber>')
```

Comment: That didn't work for my using iOS Simulator 10.0 (835.5) but I was able to work around using `replaceText()`

Answer (score 6):

please checkout here:
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md

on typeText() method

> Note: Make sure hardware keyboard is disconnected. Otherwise, Detox
>   may fail when attempting to type text.
>
> To make sure hardware keyboard is disconnected, open the simulator
>   from Xcode and make sure Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware
>   Keyboard is deselected (or press ⇧⌘K).

Comment: @ϹοδεMεδιϲ this is an answer?

Comment: @ϹοδεMεδιϲ it was an answer, not a question

Comment: Doh! RTFT for me!

Comment: is there a way to set this setting in the device configuration, something like device.launchApp({ delete: true, launchArgs: { ConnectHardwareKeyboard: false } })

Answer (score 0):

I tried the various solutions listed here, but no avail.

What worked consistently for me was:

- Tap on any text field in your app
- *Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard (⌘K)*

The reason this works is because it automatically toggles the builtin keyboard on anytime a text field element is tapped, which is a mandatory prerequisite when calling `typeText`.

I've added a [pull request](https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/1437) to update the documentation which has now been approved.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to get get the software keyboard work consistently but `.replaceText()` did work pretty well for me. `waitFor()` was also very useful.